# How do I use Photoshop via wine on Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: wine, photoshop

If you have any experiences on using Photoshop via Wine then please share with me about your experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time ago I tried to use Photoshop on Linux; after spending several days trying to get used to Wine problems managing Photoshop to avoid having to use VirtualBox, I did it. If you have enough RAM and you need to use it for professional issues, **I would recommend you to choose this option (VirtualBox. I would use version 5).**

Comment: Thanks Brother ! 
Thats a great suggestion. I tried before some time ago but not worked properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use playonlinux.

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

then open playonlinux and click install
wait for it to download the list and then close playonlinux
then reopen it and click install, then install a non listed program, follow the steps.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can always search the wine database for the relevant applications. In this case that would be [here](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=25607) and [here](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?bIsQueue=false&bIsRejected=false&sClass=application&sTitle=Browse+Applications&iItemsPerPage=25&iPage=1&sOrderBy=appName&bAscending=true).

Comment: i knew that. My question is about experiences if anybody uses.

Comment: @FaysalHasan Entries in the winehq app database actually are experiences from other users.